# Forward Slash "/" key opening "Gnome Help"

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I've done a yum update today (CentOS 7) and after that my forward slash key is now opening "Gnome Help" every time I press it. It is driving me insane because I have to use the numpad divide symbol to type that key now.

Is there a way to fix this? Even if I have to "hack" the system into thinking this key is the forward slash key I don't care.

Comment: System Settings --> Keyboard --> Launchers . Do you see `/` being assigned to something ?

Comment: There was no shortcut for "/" specifically, but there were some that were words and I didn't know what keys they represented, I deleted them all and the forward slash key is now working properly, thanks!

Comment: To be clearer, The "Settings" shortcut was set to the word "Tools", I don't know what key is "Tools" but deleting that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Answer your own question, and set it as the correct answer - no sense leaving it open :)

Answer (score 1):

Following MelBurslan advice,

System Settings -> Keyboard -> Launchers, The "Settings" shortcut was set to the word "Tools", I don't know what key is "Tools" but deleting that fixed the problem.